Can reinforcement learning rewards be a combination of current and new state?
I'm structuring the reward function for my RL agent and considering a combination of both the current state and the new state after taking an action. From what I understand, this is possible based on Sutton & Barto, particularly Equation 3.6, where the reward is a function of the state-action pair and the resulting state. I want to ensure that my approach is in line with RL theory.
Could anyone confirm if this is valid or share insights?
$$r(s, a, s') \doteq \mathbb{E} [R_t \mid S_{t-1} = s, A_{t-1} = a, S_t = s'] = \sum_{r \in \mathcal{R}} r \frac{p(s', r \mid s, a)}{p(s' \mid s, a)}$$

The equation you presented is the expected reward function, which will always produce the same scalar value for a specific $(s, a, s')$ tuple. An essential concern when designing the reward signal for an RL environment is that sampling the reward signal should be relatively easy; computing the expected reward is not usually a consideration. A sample reward is still a scalar, but two sample rewards may be different even for the same $(s, a, s')$ tuple due to stochasticity in the dynamics function. The dynamics function details the probability of sampling a next state $s'$ and reward $r$ given the current state $s$ and action $a$, as follows:
\begin{align}
&p:\mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{R} \times \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{A} \rightarrow [0, 1],\\
&p(s', r|s, a) = \mbox{Pr}(S_t{=}s', R_t{=}r\ |\ S_{t-1}{=}s, A_{t-1}{=}a).
\end{align}
Clearly, the probability of sampling reward $r$ is dependent on current state $s$ and the action $a$ from the conditional notation. Sutton & Barto clarify in section 3.8 remark 3.1 that the dynamics function was written as a joint probability to emphasize that the probabilities of sampling $s'$ and $r$ are jointly determined (not independently determined). Therefore, the probability of sampling reward $r$ generally can depend on the new state $s'$ in addition to the current state $s$ and action $a$.

Yes, it is valid within the MDP framework to base immediate reward on current state, action and next state, plus a random factor. Or any subset and combination.
The important detail is that the starting state and selected action must be the only non-stochastic influences on both the immediate reward and the next state. So for your three part function to work within the theory, the state transition rules must also follow the $p(s'|s,a)$ formulation strictly. If they do so, then the factor of which next state $s'$ we end up in before determining $r$ is just a fixed probability tree, and you can combined same $r$ values as necessary then calculate the distribution and expectations of $r$ independently of knowing $s'$. The values you get will still depend on whether you know $s'$, but doing the calculations for $r$ do not require you to know it - importantly this means you can select an optimal/greedy action based on knowing $s, a$ only and predicting the expected returns, without needing to know $s'$ in advance.
Another way to put this: The values of $s'$ and $r$ can be correlated without breaking any of the rules of MDPs that are used to prove reinforcement learning works.
